# Inserting string at end of linked list

Tags: c++

I am inserting a string at the end of a linked list. When I compile my file I get 2 errors:

error: ‘setData’ was not declared in this scope
      setData(*string_p);

error: ‘getNext’ was not declared in this scope
        newNode = getNext();

However they are defined before I use them (defined in above methods) so I do not understand the error.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using std::string;
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    #define SUCCESS 0
    #define FAIL    1


    // Represents an entry object in the linked-list
    class ListEntry
    {
    public:
    explicit     ListEntry();
    explicit     ListEntry(const char *string_p);
             ~ListEntry();
    string       getData();
    void         setData(const char* string_p);
    void         setData(string string);
    ListEntry   *getNext();
    ListEntry   *getPrevious();
    ListEntry   *prev_p;   // pointer to previous entry in the linked-list
    ListEntry   *next_p;   // pointer to next entry in the linked-list

    private:
    string          data;      // entry's string
    };

    // Represents the linked-list object
    class List
    {
    public:
    List();
    ~List();

    bool printForward();
    bool printReverse();
    bool insert(const char *string_p);

    private:
    int        entryCount;  // number of entries present in the linked-list
    ListEntry *head_p;      // pointer to the first entry in the list
    ListEntry *tail_p;      // pointer to the last entry in the list
    };

    // ListEntry constructor
    ListEntry::ListEntry()
    {
    this->prev_p = NULL;
    this->next_p = NULL;
    return;
    }

    // ListEntry constructor
    ListEntry::ListEntry(const char *string_p)
    {
    this->data   = string_p;
    this->prev_p = NULL;
    this->next_p = NULL;
    return;
    }

    // List entry destructor 
    ListEntry::~ListEntry()
    {
    return;
    }

    // Return the stored string object
    string ListEntry::getData()
    {
    return this->data;
    }

    // Set the internal string data from a char*
    void ListEntry::setData(const char* string_p)
    {
    this->data = string_p;
    }

    // Set the internal string data from a string
    void ListEntry::setData(string string)
    {
    this->data = string;
    }

    // Returns reference to the next entry in the list
    ListEntry *ListEntry::getNext()
    {
    return this->next_p;
    }

    // Returns reference to the previous entry in the list
    ListEntry *ListEntry::getPrevious()
    {
    return this->prev_p;
    }
```

And my Insert function (which is below the above methods in my program):

```
    bool List::insert(const char *string_p)
    {
      // Please write the list insert function

        //new node to be inserted
        ListEntry* newNode = new ListEntry();
        //List *newList = new List();

        if(newNode == NULL)
        {
          cout << "FAILED";
        }
        else
        {
          setData(*string_p); //////ERROR HERE
          if(this->head_p = NULL)
          {
            newNode = getNext(); //////ERROR HERE
            newNode = this->head_p;
            this->head_p = newNode; // newNode now points to the head node
            this->entryCount++;
            return SUCCESS;
          }
          else
          {
            ListEntry* temp = this->head_p;
            while(temp -> next_p != NULL)
            {
              temp = temp -> next_p;
            }
            temp -> next_p = newNode;
            this->entryCount++;
            return SUCCESS;
          }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Also, setData(*string_p); should be setData(string_p);

Comment: `setData` and `getNext` belong to `ListEntry` but you are using them with `this` in a method that belongs to `List`. Did you mean `newNode->getNext();` and `newNode->setData(string_p);` ?

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the functions but you are not using them the way you have defined:

```
setData(*string_p); // Takes a const char*, but you have provided a char.
                    // *string_p dereferences the string pointer, giving the 
                    // first char.
newNode = getNext(); // getNext is a ListEntry function, but you are trying
                     // to use it in the context of List. This is also true of the 
                     // above function.
```

Comment: But setData() takes 'const char* string_p' and i am passing 'const char *string_p'. There the same type right?

Comment: @guy No, you are passing `*string_p` which is `const char *` dereferenced. ie, a char.

Comment: SO if I dont dereference i.e get rid of the *, they should both be of the same type?

Comment: @guy: correct. Don't add the star and it will compile.

Answer (score 0):

The functions `setData` and `getNext` are non-static member functions of the class `ListEntry`. So they have to be called using a member access expression.

Moreover the supplied argument of this call

```
setData(*string_p);
```

has different type than the the function expects.

You have to write at least like

```
newNode->setFata( string_p );
```

and

```
newNode->getNext();
```

though this code snippet even if the call of the function will be correct from the syntax point of view does not make sense

```
      if(this->head_p = NULL)
      {
        newNode = newNode->getNext();
        newNode = this->head_p;
```

because there is at least a memory leak.

Also this if statement

```
if(newNode == NULL)
```

will make sense if you use the following call of the new operator

```
ListEntry* newNode = new ( std::nothrow ) ListEntry();
```

The function can look the following way

```
bool List::insert( const char *string_p )
{
    //new node to be inserted
    ListEntry *newNode = new ( std::nothrow ) ListEntry( string_p );

    bool success = newNode != nullptr;

    if ( success )
    {
        if ( tail_p )
        {
            tail_p->next_p  = newNode;
            newNode->prev_p = tail_p;  
        }
        else
        {
            head_p = newNode;
        }

        tail_p = newNode;
        entryCount++;
    }

    return success;
}
```

Comment: The idea there is if the head pointer is null, Make newNode the new Head pointer. My code compiles now but I have seg faults. Any thoughts?

Comment: @guy As I wrote this code does not make sense.

Comment: Any suggestions where this leak is?

Comment: @guy Read you own code. At first you allocated dynamically an object and its address was stored in the variable bewNode. And then the variable was overwritten. So the address of the allocated memory was lost.

Comment: @guy See my updated post.

Answer (score 0):

Your `insert()` method is implemented all wrong.  It should look more like this instead:

```
int List::insert(const char *string_p)
{
    //new node to be inserted
    ListEntry* newNode = new ListEntry(string_p);

    if (newNode == NULL)
    {
        cout << "FAILED";
        return FAIL;
    }

    if (this->head_p == NULL) {
        this->head_p = newNode;
    }

    if (this->tail_p != NULL)
    {
        this->tail_p->next_p = newNode;
        newNode->prev_p = this->tail_p;
    }
    this->tail_p = newNode;

    this->entryCount++;
    return SUCCESS;
}
```